# How to get element's data value using oninput event

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get element's data in the way like in the example below
or - any similar way - except `addEventListener`

currently I'm getting error - `e` is not defined

Expecting result should be - `lorem` - `ipsum` - `dolor` - by typing inside the three inputs respectively

```js
function on_input(e){
    let a = e.target.data('x');
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='inp' oninput="on_input()" data-x='lorem'>
<input type='text' class='inp' oninput="on_input()" data-x='ipsum'>
<input type='text' class='inp' oninput="on_input()" data-x='dolor'>
```

Comment: You need to pass `event` as argument for `oninput` event handler. Also, to read the data attributes, Use `e.target.dataset.x`. `Elem.data()` is jQuery version of the same.

Comment: Massive dupe. Please look before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the element as parameter into the function.

```js
function on_input(elem){
    let a = elem.getAttribute("data-x");
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='inp' oninput="on_input(this)" data-x='lorem'>
<input type='text' class='inp' oninput="on_input(this)" data-x='ipsum'>
<input type='text' class='inp' oninput="on_input(this)" data-x='dolor'>
```

Comment: Op wanted event in the function. This is a massive dupe in any case

Comment: bcoz obvious duplicate question, is ask every day

Comment: @mplungjan he does not say that. This is no doubt a dupe but my answer does what he asked 1000%.

Comment: so does `oninput="on_input(event)"` without having to change the function except for e.target.dataset.x to get the attribute.